# Connectivity issue between containers (I suppose...)

Tags: java, docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run 3 containers:

1. My webapplication
2. Postgres
3. Cassandra

Once I use: `docker-compose up`

My webapp launches this exception:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s)
> tried for query failed (tried: cassandra/172.17.0.3:9042

Once all containers are running, I'm able to enter into my webapps and try to ping cassandras container before it dies (webapp container), and all packets are successfully returned so I guess there actually IS connectivity between them.

The weirdest thing is that once I got this exception:

> .InvalidQueryException: Keyspace 'myKeyspace' does not exist

Which means connection has been stablished, but was before I add persistence and created the mentioned schema, but I did change nothing on my compose.yml to get this new result

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1' 

services:


cassandra:
    container_name: "cassandra"
    image: cassandra
    ports:
        - 9042:9042
    
    
    volumes:
      - /home/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra

     
postgresql:
 
    container_name: "postgresql"
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: mywebapp
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
       #- ./startup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup.sql 
       - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    
    

mywebapp:
    container_name: "mywebapp"
    image: openjdk:10-jre-slim
    hostname: mywebapp
    volumes:
        - ./lib:/home/lib
        - ./mywebapp-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:/home/mywebapp-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
        
       
    entrypoint:     
        - java
        - -jar
        - -Djava.library.path=/home/lib
        - /home/mywebapp-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
    
    environment:
        - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/lib
        - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/mywebapp
        - spring.cassandra.contactpoints=cassandra
        - spring.cassandra.port=9042
        - spring.cassandra.keyspace=mywebapp
        #- spring.datasource.username=postgres
        #- spring.datasource.password=postgres
        #- spring.jpa.hibernate.ddlAuto=update+
       
        
        
    ports:
        - 8443:8443
        - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
        - cassandra
```

volumes:
postgresdata:

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your web app requires for the cassandra service to be running when it starts. You should add `depends_on` entry to your web app service so docker starts it only when cassandra is started

And the `links` entry is not necessary as docker automatically will use the service names as hostnames in the network created for this docker-compose project. Same goes for the `network_type: bridge` - that is the default network type, so you can omit that in your case.

Comment: Thanks for you asnwer, i just eddited how my compose.yml looks like now. Still getting exactly same issue. Dunno if i did it correctly

Comment: My guess is that cassandra has some time for it to startup? Some init process, which may take a little too long, so docker assumes that the service is started (because it is, it just needs to do additional startup things) so it feels like it's good to start your web app as well... You can try to create a wrapper shell script around your web app and use it as entrypoint for your container, and before starting the application actually check if the cassandra is accessible. Or you can try defining a healthcheck command for cassandra service

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra check the part about "No connections until Cassandra init completes"
You can use a simple while loop in bash and check if the cassandra is accessible with some netcat or similar tools

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201601.mbox/%3C568E437D.90902@francelabs.com%3E This seems like a good way to start looking for a solution

Comment: THANKS!!!!! I just used a sleep command and LOOKS like it works (now I need to handle the last exception, or hope so), but no more cassandra related exceptions launched. Obviously I'll improve the implicit waiting but now knowing the source of the excepcion gonna be way easier to handle, thank you so much!!